# Setting bitmap to imageview from filepath is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap, imageview

I tried almost all methods possible to set image to a `image-view` from stored file path.

None of them work.
The images were selected from gallery in other activity and imagepath stored into database.

**Images are of type** *.jpg .jpeg .png*

Image paths  stored in database with paths without any extensions

```
eg.  /external/storage/media/carimagename
```

when I try to set image to `imageview` using this code there is no error but image is not set.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listview_arraypro1[i]);
 carpict.setImageBitmap(pic);

    /// File imgFile =new File("listview_arraypro1[i]");
    // carpict.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()));



          // Bitmap carpic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
          // carpic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(carpic, 72, 70, false); 

 }
```

How can i set the images with path format `/external/storage/media/carimagename` to an `imageview`?

Im using the following to get the image path in previous activity

```
             Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

           String  selectedImagePath = selectedImage.getPath();
```

Am i getting the wrong path from selectedImagePath?

this is the path i got using this which had no mnt/sdcard

```
  private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }
}



    File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
           String path= imageFile.toString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing is that first you have to need mentioned your image type in your image path...

And after then you can retrieve using that imagepath:

```
String img_path = "image will be with image type";       
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path);
ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

you should add permission to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: none of the answers worked :(   Also tried giving image path String img_path ="/storage/sdcard0/Fbt/xylo.jpg"; Still didnt work!

Comment: have you add permission for it??

Comment: i had not put the read permissions,now i have put that too but still it is not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36703/discussion-between-metalhead1247-and-piyush-gupta)

Comment: i have updated the question i got the correct path as /storage/sdcard0/Fleet/xylo.jpg with the extension there was no /mnt/sdcard root

Comment: the problem was with the image itself, when i tried with other images it worked, but xylo.jpg is not getting set don't know why

Answer (score 2):

Take a gander at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334529/setting-imageview-image-using-path-of-file-from-external-storage).

You can use the `ImageView.setImageURI(..)` methode.

```
preview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Echo/Images/"+file_name));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Image paths stored in database with paths without any extensions
```

You need to mention image type in path. e. image.png

You can try like following example.

```
String imagePath = "your image path with image type";   //eg. /sdcard/img.PNG      
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
  ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);// your imageview
  myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```