# How can i set the bitmap to the imageView?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have been struggling with setting an image (that i fetch using the uri) into an `ImageView`.

**What i am doing ?**

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<Attachment> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(Attachment imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<Attachment>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        return ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imageViewReference.get().getPath(), 200, 100);
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final Attachment imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else {
                Log.v("BLAH[Inner]", (imageViewReference ==null) +""+(bitmap == null));
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.v("BLAH", (imageViewReference ==null) +""+(bitmap == null));
        }
    }
}
```

*I have confirmed that the uri is correct , and the absolute path to the image is also correct(which is set in the path property of the Attachment object).Plus the bitmap is not null.*

But the imageView is still not showing the image.

**UPDATE**
The image is not being shown on the first time but works everytime after that.Weird thing is that nothing shows up on the logcat as well.

**Caution** :

Bad variable name used(refactoring went wrong)

**Default image(set in the xml) does show however.Take a look**

[image: Default image]

*I used hierarchy viewer to check into the layout.*

[image: Here's what it looks like...]

Comment: sorry to ask this, have you confirmed that the AsyncTask is started?

Comment: oh..yes i did an execute ... :-)

Comment: Maybe you should add a log inside `if (imageView != null) {` as well to see when it is called

Comment: Done...its coming inside that if.

Comment: Also, you may want to add a default android:src first to see if it is displayed properly

Comment: Yes that gets displayed too..I had that set in the xml ...

Comment: so,it is the old image which keeps here? or it becomes blank. Maybe you would want to post the code where the call to execute AsyncTask is made

Comment: it becomes blank...with only the orange background.

Comment: I am getting the image now without doing any change..I did not get what happened

Comment: My guess would be your ImageResizer class was not renewed on your apk

Comment: But the first time it does not get displayed, when i choose the image second time it gets displayed

Comment: May i know why is it getting downvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have added permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Sometimes we miss small things.

Comment: The image that i am fetching is local (in the phone) uri.

Comment: try checking for read and write permissions if not already added, cause Your code looks right.
One other way to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459941/setting-bitmap-to-imageview-from-filepath-is-not-working

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

This is in the manifest.I am sure that'll do

Answer (score 0):

You are using setImageBitmap which works always but you can use the following snippet code.

```
BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
```

Comment: might be the reference of **profilePic** is not correct that's why it's not showing. Add your full code here so we achieve the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

to

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provide, it seems that either the file has problem, or it is the `ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile` not working, returned an empty or transparent Bitmap.

Can you add this code in `onPostExecute` and post the result?

```
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
Log.v("BLAH", "width : " + width);
Log.v("BLAH", "height : " + height);
if(width > 0 && height > 0) {
    Log.v("BLAH", "pixel : " + bitmap.getPixel(width/2,height/2));
}
```

Comment: I am using this snippet from developer's guide...https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Isnt it correct..It seems so.

Comment: please check my update, see if you can try to add this log

Comment: width : 12
height : 9
pixel : -7240337

Comment: it is a real tiny image you get as a result , 12 x 9 pixels

Comment: actually I think I can find it on the image you uploaded, is it set to center horizontal and align top?

Comment: Yes i see it too in hierarchy viewer.

Comment: But if its an image , and i have already specified height and width , why is it so small then ?

Comment: As I said, it has to be a problem in ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile unless the source image itself is really so small

Comment: So when i changed my inputs from 200,100 to 2000,1000.I see width and height go large...But still it does not get displayed