# Show ImageView from file couldn't found this file

Tags: android

I need to show image from the File type, this my code snippet :

```
//Part 1 how I'm setting my file (picking image from gallery)
    currImageURI = data.getData();
    myImage= new File(currImageURI.getPath());

//Part 2 how I'm trying to show my image from the File
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iv.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(myImage));
```

This is the value of `myImage` while debuging :

> path : /document/image:19144

This is valid path and valid Image, but I got this Error :

> resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///document/image%3A19144

So what's the problem over here ? 
I h've to use the FILE type. Show image from File type .

Comment: try using directly 
iv.setImageURI(data.getData());

Comment: I need to use the FILE type (the myImage Variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/image")));
```

Or with:

```
ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(new File("/path/to/image").toString()));
```

Updated

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
InputStream imageStream = null;
try {
    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle the error
} finally {
    if (imageStream != null) {
        try {
            imageStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore the exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The path is getted automaticly and stored in FILE type (the myImage var ) so I need to use the myImage Var

Comment: ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(myImage));

Comment: Have you read my Post? try the last solution you gave is what i have been using

Comment: Are you picking image from gallery ?

Comment: You didn't get the point, The Image selectede from the gallery need to be stored in **FILE type** then when needed I have to display this image so I've to use **ImageView with File Type**

Comment: I think this tread will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074845/android-choose-image-from-gallery-and-store-it-in-a-file-type-variable . Regards

Answer (score -1):

This is how I have done it. Try it once

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Comment: I need to correct my code not to change the hole code

Comment: @Chlebta can u check this lnk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095676/resolveuri-failed-on-bad-bitmap-uri-when-putting-image-on-listview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334529/setting-imageview-image-using-path-of-file-from-external-storage?rq=1